# Chrome + Lucida Grande + Word-wrap

Tags: css, google-chrome

I've got an odd combination of styles that's leading to an issue in Chrome only. I've put together a fiddle to showcase the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/C3CbF/1/

This will only work, of course, if you have the Lucida Grande font installed - otherwise they'll look the same. But if you have Lucida Grande, you'll notice that the last "t" in "Test" in the first table, only in Chrome (and possibly only on Mac - I haven't tested a PC), breaks down to a second line while the second table is just fine.

So, my question is, without removing any styles (like word-wrap or the font), is there a way to have this not break (or, break appropriately)?

Also note that `white-space: nowrap` won't work in this scenario, because I WOULD like a single word to break if it's longer than 300px (like in the case of a URL).

Answer (score 1):

I don`t have Lucida Grande font, but I know best cross-browser solution for [no]wrapping text. Check this out:

```
.nowrap {
    -webkit-white-space: nowrap;
    -khtml-white-space: nowrap;
    -moz-white-space: nowrap;
    -ms-white-space: nowrap;
    -o-white-space: nowrap;
    white-space: nowrap;

    word-wrap: normal;

    -webkit-word-break: keep-all;
    -khtml-word-break: keep-all;
    -moz-word-break: keep-all;
    -ms-word-break: keep-all;
    -o-word-break: keep-all;
    word-break: keep-all;
}
```

See more: http://jsfiddle.net/iegik/ymSse/